# what is the pythonic way to write this code?

Tags: python-3.x

How do I write this entire code in only one line?

```
for i in range(len(array)):
    if array[i] - 1 > 0:
        array[i] -= 1
    else:
        array[i] = 0
```

I have tried this but doesn't work:

```
(array[i] -= 1 if array[i] - 1 > 0 else array[i] = 0) for i in range(len(array))
```

Comment: Maybe start of by not using “array” as the variable name because since it is not an array

Comment: @FishballNooodles That is not an answer to the question, so "start of" has no use here. Also, `array` is fine, since a Python list is called array in various other languages, and it doesn't overwrite a built-in name.

Comment: A python list is NOT equivalent to an array in other languages. Especially since other languages do NOT supoort variable types in a single sequence.

Comment: @FishballNooodles How not?

Comment: Array and List are 2 different things in Python itself. Array assumes the use of numpy.

Comment: No, it does not assume the use of NumPy. The Python stdlib has its own [arrays](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html), for example.

Comment: And JavaScript arrays are very similar to Python lists: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the elements instead of the numerator in your list comprehension, since `i` is only used for indexing into the array, not for anything else (thus `i` can be left out, and an iteration over the elements suffies):

```
array = [0 if item - 1 <= 0 else item - 1 for item in array]
```

Comment: He wants to edit the list, not create another

Comment: @Siscall I'm assigning the new list to the same variable name.

Comment: Ok. But still it overwrites the older one. Not the same id.

Comment: How would that matter here?

Comment: Well that works so no problem.

Comment: @Siscall, wouldn't it take another space? ie space complexity = O(n)?